# How to make css search form responsive

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive-design

i am trying to make use of min-width , max-width property but was unable to achieve the results as desired.

here is the code

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-wrapper-01">
<input id="search" type="text" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
   .form-wrapper-01 {
    max-width: 450px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #dedede #bababa #aaa #bababa;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f6f6f6), to(#eae8e8));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6, #eae8e8);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6, #eae8e8);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6, #eae8e8);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6, #eae8e8);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6, #eae8e8);
    }

.form-wrapper-01 #search {
max-width: 330px;
width:100%;
height: 20px;
padding: 10px 5px;
float: left;
font: bold 16px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
border: 1px solid #ccc;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.form-wrapper-01 #search:focus {
outline: 0;
border-color: #aaa;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #bbb inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #bbb inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #bbb inset;
}

.form-wrapper-01 #search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #999;
font-weight: normal;
font-size:12px;
font-style:italic;
}

.form-wrapper-01 #search:-moz-placeholder {
color: #999;
font-weight: normal;
font-size:12px;
font-style:italic;
}

.form-wrapper-01 #search:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: #999;
font-weight: normal;
font-size:12px;
font-style:italic;
}

.form-wrapper-01 #submit {
float: right;
border: 1px solid #00748f;
height: 42px;
max-width: 100px;
width:100%;
padding: 0;
cursor: pointer;
font: bold 15px Arial, Helvetica;
color: #fafafa;
text-transform: none;
background-color: #0483a0;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#31b2c3), to(#0483a0));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

.form-wrapper-01 #submit:hover,
.form-wrapper-01 #submit:focus {
background-color: #31b2c3;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0483a0), to(#31b2c3));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0483a0, #31b2c3);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0483a0, #31b2c3);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0483a0, #31b2c3);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0483a0, #31b2c3);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0483a0, #31b2c3);
}

.form-wrapper-01 #submit:active {
outline: 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}

.form-wrapper-01 #submit::-moz-focus-inner {
border: 0;
}
```

here is live example

http://jsfiddle.net/6TUem/

as you can see the problem is with search button which shift itself in next line when you resize the window.i want it to stick with the input [text] field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6TUem/2/)?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    .form-wrapper-01 #submit {
        float: none;
        max-width: none;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
    .form-wrapper-01 #search {
        max-width: none;
        width: 100%%;
    }
}
```

(Admittedly, I did change some things such as box-sizing.)

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but this look like a better solution. answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the input in a div and then use some style like this:

```
.form-wrapper-01 {
   background-color: #f3f3f3;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 450px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   text-align: right;
   padding: 10px;
}

#search {
   background-color: #ff0000;
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   right: 100px;
}

#search input {
   width: 100%;
}

#submit {
   width: 80px;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6TUem/4/

Comment: what was that where is responsiveness

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missed something on your question. I edited my answer.